# css calc от чего берется 100%

Tags: css, css3

Откуда берется 100% в выражении

**`height: calc(100%-65px);`**

От высоты родителя? А если высота родителя явно не указана?

Comment: если явно не указана, то она `initial`, тобишь по умолчанию. А какая у кого высота по умолчанию, зависит от элемента.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вначале внутри функции `calc()` будет приведен тип — от `<percentage>` к `<length>`, затем будет вычислено выражение. Если элемент имеет значение свойства `position`, отличное от `absolute` и у родителя не задана явным образом высота, то `height` унаследует значение `auto` и результатом работы функции будет `auto`.

Если у элемента задан `position: absolute`, то его высота будет равняться 100% высоты ближайшего `position: relative`-родителя минус 65 пикселей.

Если ближайший родитель с `position: relative` так и не будет найден, то высота будет считаться от высоты `body`.

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.container-setheight {
  height: 200px;
}

.container-noheight {
  height: auto;
}

.container-abs {
  position: relative;
}

.container-abs-abs {
  
}

.first {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

.second {
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  background-color: yellow;
}

.container-abs .second,
.container-abs-abs .second {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container container-setheight">
  Высота задана = 200 пикселей
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second">calc(100% - 10px)</div>
</div>

<div class="container container-noheight">
  Высота не задана<br>
  position: static; + position: static;
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second">calc(100% - 10px)</div>
</div>

<div class="container container-abs">
  Высота не задана<br>
  position: relative; + position: absolute;
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second">calc(100% - 10px)</div>
</div>

<div class="container container-abs-abs">
  Высота не задана<br>
  position: static; + position: absolute;
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second">calc(100% - 10px)</div>
</div>
```